# Yii Framework - URL mapping to action

Tags: php, yii

I have the following rule, in my **config/main.php**:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<param:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Can I have in `ExperienceController` an action `actionListByDistrict($param)` that is called when the URL `/mysite/experience/district/value` is used?

I would like to do a kind of mapping in Yii Framework, but how? Actually the action takes this form: `actionDistrict($param)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that I mention on the comment should work:

```
'experience/district/<param:\w+>'=>'experience/listByDistrict'
```

Make sure this specific rule stays on top, because the order on Yii UrlManager Rules matters.

About the general rule however, I don't see way for doing it atm.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try that `'experience/district/<id:\d+>'=>'experience/listByDistrict/',`

Comment: id expects a number (d+) and the param is a word. So changing to w+ and use param instead of id may work instead? Still, the OP may wish to a have a general regex rule, so that it doesn't end with 10 lines of code, when one would be enough.

Comment: `'experience/district/<param:\w+>'=>'experience/listByDistrict/',` still doesn't solve. The system looks for an action called `district`. And as @MEM said, it would be interesting if there was a general rule for it, considering the last word of `listByDistrict`.